# How to use angular material autocomplete using angular signals

Tags: angular, autocomplete, signals

angular documentation did not show any suggestion for autocomplete and autoselect with filtering using angular signals . Autocomplete works for observables but not for signals. Any one who can suggest that how i can get the same result by using angular signal in angular material. Because angular signal are not mentioned in detail in the angular documentation